# Changing background color (or just color) of row (javafx)

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I've a `TableView`. I want to change background color of rows according to some condition. For instance, if balance (`getBalance()`) is less than zero - set background color of that row to red. Here is my `setCellValueFactory`:

```
tc_proj_number.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getId().toString()));
tc_proj_date.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getValueDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate().toString()));
tc_proj_amount.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getBalance().setScale(2).toPlainString()));
tc_proj_comment.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getComment()));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [TableColumn#setCellFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) method.
Try the following code (not tested):

```
tc_proj_amount.setCellFactory(column -> {
    return new TableCell<Account, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item);
                // Style row where balance < 0 with a different color.
                BigDecimal balance = new BigDecimal(item);
                TableRow currentRow = getTableRow();

                if (balance.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) < 0) {            
                    currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                } else currentRow.setStyle("");
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: What do item and empty stand for? In my case it returns null and false all the time

Comment: Sorry, I'm done. I've deleted my SetCellValueFactory and used your, and they should go together. Thanks a lot