# JavaFX : Coloring TableView row and formatting the cell text

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I've a `TableView` (located inside a `ScrollPane`), one of the rows is as follows:

```
tc_proj_amount.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
     new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getBalance().toPlainString()));
```

I want to color the whole row where `tc_proj_amount` is negative. For this purpose I use this:

```
tc_proj_amount.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<Transaction, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);

                } else {

                    setText(item);

                    // Style row where balance < 0 with a different color.
                    BigDecimal balance = new BigDecimal(item);
                    if (balance.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) < 0) {
                        TableRow currentRow = getTableRow();
                        currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato;");

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

When I run my app, rows are colured as needed, but when I scroll up-down a list more and more rows become coloured, even when `tc_proj_amount` is not negative. When I try to sort columns, all rows become coloured. How can I fix this problem?

2nd question. I want to somehow format the value of `tc_proj_amount`. For this purpose I did this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
tc_proj_amount.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
 new SimpleStringProperty(df.format(cellData.getValue().getBalance()).toString()));
```

Part that changes row colour is the same as above. In this case I receive an exception. How can  I fix it?

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

Exception is pointing into part where rows are colored.

Comment: for the first part, looks like you didn't read the update of the accepted answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31902910/203657) Btw, better not mix separate questions into one (the formatting is unrelated to the coloring)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The rule of thumb when overriding the `updateItem()` method is to handle all cases of logical branching. Just like as `setText()` for both item empty and non-empty cases, you need to set the color when the balance>=0 (i.e. the "else" case). In future, you are likely go with using css selectors instead of inline styling, so the common approach will be:

```
if(condition)
    item.getStyleClass().add("css");
else
    item.getStyleClass().remove("css");
```

2) You already have a cellFactory, format the text in there, no need for cellValueFactory.

```
setText(df.format(item));
```

Comment: For the first part I just had to add else  currentRow.setStyle(""); For the second part, I got the point. It should be setText(df.format(balance).toString());

Comment: @sher repeating: the first part was already answered in your last question ... ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra, I saw. You don't have to repeat)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your first question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12425646

In summary the cells are being destroyed and recreated when scrolling, and indirectly destroying your colour changes.

Comment: Hmm, I already saw that it is destroyed. The problem is how to fix it. That post doesn't answer my question