# Colouring table row in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088011/javafx-coloring-tableview-row-and-formatting-the-cell-text/32090142?noredirect=1#comment52079633_32090142). Now I want to colour the row where field value equals to some value.

```
    @FXML
    private TableView<FaDeal> tv_mm_view;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<FaDeal, String> tc_inst;
    tc_inst.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(""+cellData.getValue().getInstrumentId()));

    tc_inst.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<FaDeal, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);

                } else {

                    setText(item);
                    // Style row where balance < 0 with a different color.

                    TableRow currentRow = getTableRow();
                    if (item.equals("1070")) {
                        currentRow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato;");

                    } else currentRow.setStyle("");
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is I don't want to show `tc_inst` in my table. For this reason I set `visible` checkbox in `SceneBuilder` to false. In this case colouring part doesn't work at all. How can hide `tc_inst` so that colouring works?

Comment: To color the whole row, use a `rowFactory` on the table, instead of a `cellFactory` on the column. You need to post a little more information about the `TableView` and the property being tested here for a complete answer.

Comment: @James_D, but above code works well. The problem is how to hide that one column, without affecting the result. Or, did I musunderstood something?

Comment: @James_D, I've added FXML annotations and other parts related to this column. Wht I want to do is when tc_inst equals to 1070 - color row to tomato, when it is not - don't do anything. I'll repeat once more. It works good when the column is not hided, but I want to hide it somehow

Comment: I have never understood the idea that something "works good" when you say in the same breath that you can't get it to do what you want. If you can't change the color of the row without showing the column, and you don't want to show the column, then by definition it is not working the way you want.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a row factory, instead of a cell factory, if you want to change the color of the whole row:

```
tv_mm_view.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<FaDeal>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(FaDeal item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
        if (item == null) {
            setStyle("");
        } else if (item.getInstrumentId().equals("1070")) {
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato;");
        } else {
            setStyle("");
        }
    }
});
```

Note that if the value of `instrumentId` changes while the row is displayed, then the color will not change automatically with the above code, unless you do some additional work. The simplest way to make that happen would be to construct your items list with an extractor which returned the `instrumentIdProperty()` (assuming you are using the JavaFX property pattern in `FaDeal`).

Comment: With cell factory, I don't need to use an extractor.

Comment: Yes, but the cell factory won't work if the column isn't displayed. (Because the table view will not call `updateItem` on a cell factory belonging to an invisible column, for obvious reasons.) Which is kind of the point of this question...